# vlookup which feeds in several sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have got the following sheets in my excel file:

Main C&P (copy and paste) sheet – I manually insert information into the Main c&p tab which will feed into the (AAA-ZZZ sheet). 
Email sheet – Email to all the relevant users/save in email folder
AAA – ZZZ  - The other sheets will be fed through the main c&p sheet.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8g0nx2q1os4v4a/eg.png?dl=0

As you can see with the sheet with data. Throughout this sheet there is around 10,000 data items ranging from cost ctr (ABZ, INV, EDH, GLA ,GW4, CAR). You will also notice in the excel file that there are other sheets for every individual cost ctr.

Question:  Is it possible to do a vloopuk on for example "ABZ sheet as you can see above" which takes data from the Main c&p based on cell B in the main sheet which has all the cost ctr in them eg (9913ABZ = ABZ, 9913INV = INV ETC).

Please note that the other sheets abz etc all have the same columns in the same order just need right info from the Main c&p sheet.

Thanks, please let me know if any further description is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I would recommend using INDEX and MATCH, they allow you to split up the formula and reference different arrays (and sheets)

ie.

```
INDEX(--array you want to pull data from--,MATCH(--match this value--,--to this array--,--0 for exact match--),--col number if applicable--)
```

Comment: Thank you, apologies for late response but that is great thanks !

Comment: Great, anytime! If you like the answer can you select it and upvote the answer? Thank you!

Comment: apologies dont have enough reputation to do so!